# WordPress database error INSERT command denied to user 'readonly'

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with Wordpress and PHP. We had an issue in which our `w` writer db became  our reader `r` db during a fail over in the database cluster. This cause the production site to break. Currently, I'm trying to prevent the site from crashing do to this.

I get the following error from WP Engine when the database is trying to insert data into a table:

> WordPress database error INSERT command denied to user
>   'readonly'@'xx.xxx.xx.xx' for table 'responses' for query INSERT INTO
>   `responses` (`uid`, `data`) VALUES

The error is raise from the following function:

```
<?php

namespace StatCollector;

function drools_request($data, $uid) {
  try {
    $db = _get_db();
    $insertion = $db->insert("requests", [
      "uid" => $uid,
      "data" => json_encode($data),
    ]);
    if($insertion === false)  {
      throw new \Exception('Error writing to the database: ' . $db->last_error);
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
    echo 'Error writing to the database: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}
```

When the database become `--read-only` this shouldn't stop the site to work. Why isn't error handling working in this case. Does this mean that to error handle this I need to catch an `Error`? Why isn't the error handling working here?

Answer (score -1):

[Not sure this works, but it is too long for a comment]

You didn't mention your back-end database, so I bet it is MySQL because you mentioned Wordpress.

You can try to instruct mysql to throw exceptions, like this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

[class.mysqli-sql-exception](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php)

I wouldn't advice to do that in the core of wordpress itself, but you can try calling it before executing your try/catch.

Edit: Some people advice `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL` instead of `MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT`. Give it a try and see what works best in your situation.

Comment: would this mean if I add it before the try and catch that this will be fire even if there is no error?

Comment: No, it means that is how you teach mysql to throw an exception instead of creating an error. Just give it a try and see if it works (I know too little of Wordpress to speak with any authority)